# grails ajax onload and oncomplete

Tags: ajax, grails

can anyone give me sample coding that using grails ajax onload and oncomplete functions on following reader action? i want show a spinner icon while this action is onload and redirect to the list page while action is oncomplete..

```
def reader(){


            def list = []
            def dir = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Summarize_20141212/HR_FILE")
            dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
                list << file
            }
            println list
            list.each {
                File file = new File(it.path)
                def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new",
                        'postgres', 'sa', "org.postgresql.Driver")
                def lincoln = 0
                file.eachLine() { line ->
                    if (line.trim().size() == 0) {
                        return null
                    } else {
                        def field = []
                        def tokens = line.split(',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')
                        file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }
                        lincoln++
                        field.push(file.name)
                        for (String t : tokens) {
                            field.push(t)
                        }
                        while (field.size() < 10) {
                            field.push("")
                        }
                        if (lincoln > 1) {
                            sql.execute('insert into read_hr(version,col01,col02,col03,col04,col05,col06,col07,col08,col09,col10)' +
                                    'VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', field)
                            System.out.println(field);

                        }
                    }
                }


            }


redirect (action:"list")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These link will useful to you .
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/grails-ajax-examples.html
http://javadeveloper.asia/grails-ajax-tutorial-remotelink-tag